# Why is the method with const used instead of the first method which has no const

Tags: c++, function, methods, constants, overload-resolution

```
void print( int & a ){ cout << a << endl; }
void print( const int & a ){ cout << 2*a << endl; }
void print( float a ){ cout << 3*a << endl; }
```

Why is `2` the output of `print(1)`?

Comment: Is 1 constant or not?

Comment: Read about [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Comment: @doctorlove it is a constant in all countries using the _système international_, but US defines it in strange units.

Comment: The first overload is not viable - an rvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Bill Gates' compiler allowed it at least up to 2008.

Comment: @Bathsheba VS6 used to reject 2 for loops with `for (int i` at the start because the variables clashed ... somehow MS and standards don't fit in the same sentence unless it includes "have their own" ...

Comment: @Asad Masroor  Add one more overloaded function void print( int &&a ) { std::cout << 4 * a << std::endl; } and it will be called.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Why not answer, and put this at the end? I'd upvote it. (It being more useful to future readers than my answer.)

Comment: @Bathsheba You may add this to your answer.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: But that would require me knowing the precise reason. I'm a charlatan you know ;-)

Comment: @UKMonkey - VC6 actually implemented the *proposed* standard for loop variables. The rules were then modified before the standard was published, a few months after the compiler release. Could explain why MS has been reluctant to implement new proposals since?

Comment: @BoPersson interesting; but didn't really explain why they didn't release an update... I wonder how many times they've released a proposal and then gone with a slightly different version.

Comment: @UKMonkey - Yes, it was made worse by them taking 5 years to return to C++ after pushing Visual Studio.NET instead.

Answer (score 7):

The tenet of this question is that you need to know that anonymous temporaries cannot bind to non-`const` references, and they *can* bind to `const` references.

1 is an anonymous temporary of type `int`.

Hence the `const int&` binding is favoured by overload resolution.

Some compilers (older MSVC) would allow, in error, a binding to `int&`. In standard C++, if the `const int&` overload is missing, then the `float` overload will be called.

Answer (score 1):

For all three overloads:

1. (`void print( int & a ){ cout << a << endl; }`) The first overload is not called, since it only accepts a variable. (Unless you have an old MSVC compiler).
2. (`void print( const int & a )`) The second overload is of type `const int&`, which can accept either a temporary of type int, or a variable of type int.
3. (`void print( float a )`) The third overload has an argument of type float, which would work be called if there was no overload of type int.

Thus, since there is an overload that accepts a temporary variable of type int, the second overload is chosen over the third.